# Automate attaching W-2 forms for online free file (USA)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-w-2

I have had several incomes throughout the year, so manually filling out the W-2 form wastes a lot of time. I have both paper and electronic copies, so is there anyway I can directly import them in? Manually copying this in is also very error prone, so it makes no sense why one needs to do this.

At this point I'm thinking a paper filing would be even faster.

Comment: Why would you think that calculating everything yourself and sending in a paper form would be faster than using software? If you are worried that you will make a mistake simply typing the numbers you see on the form into a computer, wouldn’t you also be worried about making a mistake in doing the calculations?

Comment: When you say “online free file,” are you referring to Free File Fillable Forms, or are you referring to one of the [Guided Tax Preparation](https://www.irs.gov/filing/free-file-do-your-federal-taxes-for-free) options?

Comment: Maybe you need better tax software? Mine takes about 2 minutes per W-2.

Answer (score 4):

Some payroll companies allow automatic import of their forms in the tax software. Some tax software allows importing tax forms from some of the payroll providers and banks automatically. If your employers happen to use payroll providers that allow importing their W2s and your tax software happen to be able to import forms from these providers, then yes - there's a way to directly import them.

Since you mentioned nothing about who does the payroll or how you're filing taxes, I'm afraid I won't be able to provide a better answer.